# Spring LockRegistry: when to call LockRegistry.obtain()

Tags: java, spring, locking, spring-integration

I'm not sure when to call `RedisLockRegistry.obtain(String lockKey)` (or, more general, `LockRegistry.obtain(String lockKey)`). Should I obtain a lock only once at the start of the application and then lock it / unlock it as usual or should I obtain a lock every time before I call lock (before I use it)?

Currently I'm using the latter option, however, I'm not sure if this is really necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to understand how to use it is to follow the existing patterns in the Framework.

The simplest sample I would say is `SimpleMessageStore`:

```
@Override
public void addMessagesToGroup(Object groupId, Message<?>... messages) {
    Lock lock = this.lockRegistry.obtain(groupId);
    try {
        lock.lockInterruptibly();
        boolean unlocked = false;
        ...
        }
        finally {
            if (!unlocked) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As one place of use.

The other sample is `AbstractCorrelatingMessageHandler`:

```
@Override
protected void handleMessageInternal(Message<?> message) throws Exception {
    Object correlationKey = this.correlationStrategy.getCorrelationKey(message);
...
    UUID groupIdUuid = UUIDConverter.getUUID(correlationKey);
    Lock lock = this.lockRegistry.obtain(groupIdUuid.toString());

    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
    ...
    }
    finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

So, yes, you have always call `obtain()` before using the target `Lock` API. But in general it doesn't hurt do not reobtain it. Let's just check the `RedisLockRegistry` code:

```
public Lock obtain(Object lockKey) {
    Assert.isInstanceOf(String.class, lockKey);
    String path = (String) lockKey;
    return this.locks.computeIfAbsent(path, RedisLock::new);
}
```

The idea behind `LockRegistry` and this `obtain` is to allow end-user to get access to the shared resource (`Lock` in our case) exclusively. So, if your `key` is so global that it is just enough to get the lock for it in the beginning of your application, then it is fully up to you to keep an associated `Lock` instance.

Comment: I see, so if I need to get different locks depending on the context, I need to call `obtain()` every time the context changes, but if I only need a single lock across my application then I can call `obtain()` at the beginning and use the returned lock everywhere I need to.